# How to install Boostrap 4 (scss) on an Angular 5 project created using angular-cli

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-cli, angular5

I have created a angular 5 project, and I want to integrate Bootstrap 5 on it to be able to customise it using the scss files.

I've created the project using the angular-cli command line:

```
ng new sample-app
cd sample-app
```

Then I have added bootstrap 4 dependency to my project:

```
npm install --save bootstrap@4.1.1
```

I've set the default.StylesExt property to scss:

```
ng set defaults.styleExt=scss
```

I also renamed the extensions of the css files to scss too in order to be recognised by the compiler.

Does anybody know what else should I do in order to get the bootstrap files loaded? or bootstrapped in my app?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to tell angular CLI to add the css file.

In the angular CLI JSON file, just add:

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "styles.scss"
]
```